# Approval task from ms flow and should have the ability to select a user in a field

Tags: sharepoint-online, ms-flow

I have a document library with Manager(Person Field), Product manager(Person Field), Approval status(Single line of text), Comments(Multi lines of text) these fields. My question is can we create a flow for approval when document is uploaded if manager is provided after the upload which creates a approval task for the manager , but he should have the ability to enter Product Manager name for further approval after he approves if necessary. And if any comments are entered,those should get saved as well. Please let me know on how to create this type of flow.

Comment: @Denis Molodtsov , any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once the Flow is triggered, there is no way it can prompt the users to enter more information directly. Except for the approval feedback:

[image]

However, you can do something like this:

- Create a small Power App. It will have a people picker control.
- In your Flow, stop using the OOB approval action. Instead, send users an email with the URL to the new Power App.
- Power Apps are able to read the URL parameters you pass with the URL from Flows. This is how you will know wich workflow is currently served by the Power App.

As you can imagine, this workaround will be time consuming to implement, but I have an example of complex app that does exactly this. So I know it can be done.

Comment: will check this and will update accordingly, thank you for your input

Comment: i tried the way you suggested. came close to what we needed. thank you for your input